# How to get a forecast equation for $\hat{y}$ using ETS state space model

Tags: forecasting, exponential-smoothing

The ets(AAA) state space model ([Rob Hyndman's handbook](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ets.html)) is as below

State equation is 
\begin{equation}
Y_t = L_{t-1} + b_{t-1} + S_{t - m} + \varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

The measurement equations are
\begin{equation}
L_t = L_{t-1} + b_{t-1} + \alpha\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
b_t = b_{t-1} + \beta\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
S_t = S_{t-m} + \gamma\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}

My question is, how do I get 1 step ahead forecast from these equations considering that error component is not known for ${\hat{Y}_{t+1}}$.

Comment: Hi: This is also called the single source of error state space model. ( a kalman filter ). In order to get forecasts, you first need to estimate the filter given your data. I don't know if Rob wrote a package for doing this ? If he didn't, then you can use the DLM package inR but it will be tricky to construct the matrices correctly. I can't go into details here. Read either Rob's book or the paper at the link below. https://www.monash.edu/business/econometrics-and-business-statistics/research/publications/ebs/wp07-05.pdf.

Comment: Thanks Mlofton. I am aware of DLM package. My question was actually very much to that line.... If I am correct, I can use this as a state space model to calculate the result  just like the case given below?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212129/how-to-do-predictions-using-a-state-space-model

Comment: I have got my answer in  this book - Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing
The State Space Approach
Authors: Hyndman, R., Koehler, A.B., Ord, J.K., Snyder, R.D.

Comment: Hi: The link you pointed to is exactly what you don't want to use because that the standard KF where there are two sources of noise: one for the observation and one for system. the ETS model which is also known as single source of error state space IS A DIFFERENT formulation. For certain models ( arima(0,1,1) and arima(0,2,2) which are random walk plus noise and local linear trend, they can result in differnt answers. I can't get into this in a comment but the estimation details are different if one uses the DLM package.

Comment: Hi: I have that book but I don't know what approach Rob uses.  Assuming that  he uses an exponential smoothing approach to estimate it, then that that's fine and more straightforward. Using the DLM package will be trickier ( you can't use the C and W that giovanni uses in the book because that's for the model at the link which is different  ) but also possible.

Comment: Yes he used exponential smoothing.  You are right, estimation details are different in DLM

Comment: yes, if you want estimated parameters for any ETS type state space model,  you will need to use the DLM package but the construction of the noise term components will be totally different from examples in the DLM package. DLM really covers the "standard" KF and ETS covers the single source of error KF. But it sounds like Rob's package doesn't allow for KF estimation unfortunately.